# Year-Over-Year Percent Difference in Payments for Multiple Vendors

Tags: sql, sql-server

My database stores payments made to different vendors on a monthly basis. I am trying to calculate the most recent year-over-year percent difference in how much the vendors are paid. I keep getting errors with my code and am not sure how to finish this query. The most recent payment (ranked highest) should be the "new" factor in the ((new-old)/old ) * 100 part of the equation.

**Ideal results:**

Company A | 2015 | $400  | 0%

Company A | 2016 | $400  | 0%

Company A | 2017 | $800  | 100%

Company B | 2014 | $20    | 0%

Company B | 2015 | $30    | 50%

Company B | 2016 | $15    | -50%

Company B | 2017 | $30    | 100%

**My current results:**

Company Name | Year  | Payment 1 | Payment 2

Company A | 2015 | $400 | $400

Company A | 2016 | $400  | $400

Company A | 2017 | $800  | $800

Company B | 2014 | $20    | $20

Company B | 2015 | $30    | $30

Company B | 2016 | $15     | $15

Company B | 2017 | $30    | $30

**Here is my query:**

```
SELECT 
  [VENDOR_ID]
 ,YEAR([PMT_DATE]) as "YEAR"
 ,SUM([PMT_PER_MONTH]) as "PAYMENT"
,SUM([PMT_PER_MONTH]) as “PAYMENT 2”
      ,RANK() OVER (   PARTITION BY [VENDOR_ID]
                       ORDER BY YEAR([PMT_DATE]) ASC ) AS RANKNUM
FROM [dbo].[VendorPaymentTracker]
WHERE CAST ([PMT_DATE] as DATE) between '2012-01-01' and '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY [VENDOR_ID], year([PMT_DATE]), [PMT_PER_MONTH]
)
SELECT [VENDOR_ID], [YEAR], [PAYMENT], [PAYMENT 2]
-- ,round(([PAYMENT] – [PAYMENT 2] / [PAYMENT 2]) * 100)DIFF_PERCENT
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is `lag()`:

```
select vendor_id
       year(pmt_date) as yr
       sum(pmt_per_month) as payment,
       (sum(pmt_per_month) / nullif(lag(sum(pmt_per_month)) over (partition by vendor_id order by year(pmt_date)), 0) - 1) as increase
from dbo.VendorPaymentTracker pt
where pmt_date >= '2012-01-01' and pmt_date < '2018-01-01'
group by vendor_id, year(pmt_date);
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, I'm getting an error for dividing by zero. Adding a "nullif" before the lag function doesn't seem to work. Any tips?